# Fluid simulation sometimes works and sometimes doesnt

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have experiencing some weird issues with the fluid simulation in blender. The fluid sim sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, even when I do the exact same steps. When I open a new project I am able to make and see a simple fluid simulation (out of 2 cubes for example). However, whenever I try to apply this in a project with multiple objects it doesn't work (the domain and inflow just stay as objects). I've noticed that also when i move or resize one of the object the fluid sim also stops working. When the fluid simulation is not showing, the fps still increases and it makes a cache folder so its simulating something, but just it doesn't show. I have already tried deleting the fluid cache folders to give me a "clean slate".